# I need to separate the 2 rows on the right (2018 and 2017) so there is some whitespace. Having alot of trouble

Tags: html, css

I have a table that on the right has 2 Columns (2018 and 2017) with numbers underneath. I'm trying to separate those columns and have them separated by a white column with the border going to the end.I've added the html, I also have css but I'm just having a hard time separating while keeping the borders.

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text top-table-text">Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">2018</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Investment Securities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Loans (net of valuation reserve)<br />
        ($28,582 in 2018 &amp; $27,063 in 2017)</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,902,960</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,813,062</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Federal Funds Sold</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accured Income</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Assets</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text">Liabilities &amp; Capital Funds</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Non-Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$190,104</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$179,582</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Interest Bearing<br />
        Public Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$370,094</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$274,994</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Deposits</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">$2,857,311</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,542,877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$22,497</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$22,954</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fed Funds Purchase &amp; Other Borrowed Money</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$63,394</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Liabilities</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">$2,879,808</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold ">$2,629,225</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text">Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capital Stock</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surplus</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Undivided Proﬁts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span">(Loss) Securities</span></td>
        <td class="table-year-1">($15,384)</td>
        <td class="table-year-2">($5,558)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border">
        <td class="table-head-text">Total Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">$276,232</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">$253,898</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-head-text bk">Total Liabilities &amp; Capital Accounts</td>
        <td class="table-year-1 bold">$3,156,040</td>
        <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,883,123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border-top">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[This is the example I'm trying to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AStR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

---

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
            <th width="70%" class="table-head-text top-table-text">Assets</td>
            <th width="15%" class="table-year-1 bold">2018</td>
            <th width="15%" class="table-year-2 bold">2017</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>Cash &amp; Due From Banks</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$149,753</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$77,515</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Investment Securities</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$929,432</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$830,878</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Loans (net of valuation reserve)<br />
            ($28,582 in 2018 &amp; $27,063 in 2017)</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$1,902,960</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$1,813,062</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Federal Funds Sold</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Premises &amp; Equipment</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$49,956</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$46,666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Accured Income</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$12,652</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$12,589</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other Assets</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$111,287</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$102,413</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border">
            <td class="table-head-text">Total Assets</td>
            <td class="table-year-1 bold">$3,156,040</td>
            <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,883,123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-head-text">Liabilities &amp; Capital Funds</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Non-Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$952,623</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$894,075</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Non-Interest Bearing Public Deposits</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$190,104</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$179,582</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Interest Bearing Deposits</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$1,344,490</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$1,194,226</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Interest Bearing<br />
            Public Deposits</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$370,094</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$274,994</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border">
            <td class="table-head-text">Total Deposits</td>
            <td class="table-year-1 bold">$2,857,311</td>
            <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,542,877</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other Liabilities</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$22,497</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$22,954</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fed Funds Purchase &amp; Other Borrowed Money</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$0</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$63,394</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border">
            <td class="table-head-text">Total Liabilities</td>
            <td class="table-year-1 bold">$2,879,808</td>
            <td class="table-year-2 bold ">$2,629,225</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-head-text">Capital Accounts</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Capital Stock</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$2,500</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$2,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Surplus</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$100,943</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$79,188</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Undivided Proﬁts</td>
            <td class="table-year-1">$188,173</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">$177,768</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unrealized Gain <span class="loss-span">(Loss) Securities</span></td>
            <td class="table-year-1">($15,384)</td>
            <td class="table-year-2">($5,558)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border">
            <td class="table-head-text">Total Capital Accounts</td>
            <td class="table-year-1 bold">$276,232</td>
            <td class="table-year-2 bold">$253,898</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-head-text bk">Total Liabilities &amp; Capital Accounts</td>
            <td class="table-year-1 bold">$3,156,040</td>
            <td class="table-year-2 bold">$2,883,123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-border-top">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

---

```
table thead tr th:last-child{
  display:table;
  margin-left:90px
}
table tbody tr td:last-child{
  display:table;
  margin-left:90px
}
```